# Underlining menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to make the underlining menu item using js and jquery.
This is my code http://jsfiddle.net/naXja/9/
but my meny items don't have fixed width, so the underlining looks wrong.
Can someone to explain me how to calculate `currpos` the right way?

Comment: Include **relevant** code in your question

Comment: This is already done: http://css-tricks.com/jquery-magicline-navigation/

Comment: Refer this link [https://code.google.com/p/jquery-underline/wiki/Instructions](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-underline/wiki/Instructions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have amended part of your script so that it looks at the current items position and width instead of the "first" items (that you are calculating outside the hover event (i.e. only the once).

```
$('.nav > li').hover(function() {
    animatepos = $(this).position().left;
    thisWidth  = $(this).width();

    $('.menu-hover').stop().animate({left:animatepos, width:thisWidth}, 300);
}
, function() {
    $('.menu-hover').stop().animate({left:currpos, width:0}, 300);
});
```

Comment: I tried to apply your code and it works on jsfiddle, but it works the wrong way on may page - for `span.menu-hover` I get wrong meanings for `left`. Can you please to help me to find mistake? I uploaded my files here http://rghost.ru/48529687

Comment: Try swapping `.offset()` with `.position()`

Answer (score 1):

you can use [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) jQuery api to find elements position (non-absolute elements)

```
var currpos = $('.nav > li.active').offset().left
```

Answer (score 1):

Each element has a different width. You have to take the actual width for each element not only the one from the first.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please remove bottom hover image and use this css instead:

```
border-bottom: 1px solid red;
```

The image takes more time in image load.

Answer (score 0):

Issue with your code is you are initializing menuitemwidth on ready and assuming all the widths of menu items will be same

below is the updated code with dynamic item width and position:

```
var animatepos = $(this).offset().left;
$('.menu-hover').stop().animate({left:animatepos, width:$(this).width()}, 300);
```

Updated jsFiddle link: 
http://jsfiddle.net/naXja/16/